# Symbolic Matrix/Operator Multiplication in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

Let `A`,`B`and `C` be three 4x4 matrices defined as `A=x*P+y*Q-R`, `C=x^(-s)(L0+sL1+s^(2)L2+s^(3)L3)`.  Assuming the actual form of `P`, `Q`, `R`,`L0`,`L1`,`L2`,`L3` are not known. Can we compute symbolically, while preserving the order of multiplication (as matrices do not commute in general), the following quantity in Mathematica:$ABA C^TA^TB^TA^T$ (T=Transpose)?

Edit: $x,y,s$ are scalars and not matrices.

Comment: I assume `s`,`x`,`y` scalars and everything else is 4 by 4 matrices?

Comment: Yes, they are scalars. Just made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand):

```
r = TensorExpand[
    A . B . A . Transpose[C0] . Transpose[A] . Transpose[B] . Transpose[A],
    Assumptions -> (x|y|s) ∈ Reals
] /. Transpose[a_, {2, 1}] :> Transpose[a];
Short[r, 10]
```

> x^(4-s) P.B.P.Transpose[L0].Transpose[P].Transpose[B].Transpose[P]+x^(3-s) y P.B.P.Transpose[L0].Transpose[P].Transpose[B].Transpose[Q]-x^(3-s) P.B.P.Transpose[L0].Transpose[P].Transpose[B].Transpose[R]+x^(3-s) y P.B.P.Transpose[L0].Transpose[Q].Transpose[B].Transpose[P]+<<478>>+s^3 x^-s R.B.R.Transpose[L3].Transpose[R].Transpose[B].Transpose[R]

Comment: thanks! What is the meaning of <<478>> in the output?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Q = Array[q, {4, 4}];
R = Array[r, {4, 4}];
B = Array[b, {4, 4}];
P = Array[p, {4, 4}];
A = x*P + y*Q - R
L0 = Array[l0, {4, 4}];
L1 = Array[l1, {4, 4}];
L2 = Array[l2, {4, 4}];
L3 = Array[l3, {4, 4}];
C0 = x^(-s)*(L0 + s*L1 + s^(2)*L2 + s^(3)*L3);
res=A . B . A . Transpose@C0 . Transpose@A . Transpose@B . Transpose@A;
  
Dimensions[res]
  (* {4,4} *)
```

Result is too large to display fully

Comment: Syntax::bktmop: Expression "{4,4}*}" has no opening "{".

Comment: @User101 that is just a way to show output of the code for your convenience; that is, it is a commented out portion that is not essential to the code. Just don’t copy and paste the very last line with that in it & the code will work...